# How to add distributionSha256Sum to gradle Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, checksum, fdroid

This is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` .

```
gradle#Wed Jul 25 11:42:23 IST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

I need to add line similar to this :-

```
distributionSha256Sum=7a2c66d1a78f811d5f37d14630ad21cec5e77a2a4dc61e787e2257a6341016ce
```

How can we add **distributionSha256Sum** to `gradle-wrapper.properties` ?

why `gradle/wrapper/gradle.properties` is missing `distributionSha256Sum` is considered as a **Security Issue** ?
I am using latest Android Studio on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: "How can we add distributionSha256Sum to gradle-wrapper.properties ?" -- just put it on another line in the file, as shown in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#customizing_wrapper). However, Android Studio used to crash when the SHA-256 hash did not match the ZIP file, rather than show an error. "why gradle/wrapper/gradle.properties is missing distributionSha256Sum is considered as a Security Issue ?" -- I asked Google [nearly two years ago](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37126714) to support it.

Comment: @CommonsWare How could I get perfect sha256sum ?

Comment: You could download it, as shown in [the docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#customizing_wrapper).

Comment: @CommonsWare which file i need to download from [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#customizing_wrapper) to which folder?

Comment: The docs changed a bit in the past two years. [This sub-section](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#configuring_checksum_verification) is what I was referring to. You can find the value to use from [the distribution downloads](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/) and finding the value in the `.sha256` file corresponding with your version. Note that using this will still crash Android Studio, but 4.1 or 4.2 may soon support `distributionSha256Sum`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Just click the 2nd option and you are good to go ;)
```

https://github.com/SecUSo/privacy-friendly-ludo/issues/14

Comment: so I go to https://gradle.org/release-checksums/ ... do I need the ` Binary-only (-bin) ZIP Checksum` or the `Complete (-all) ZIP Checksum`?